# Compacting a sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I have a `id serial PRIMARY KEY` column in a PostgreSQL table. Many `id`s are missing because I have deleted the corresponding row.

Now I want to "compact" the table by restarting the sequence and reassigning the `id`s in such a way that the original `id` order is preserved. Is it possible?

Example:

- Now:

```
 id | data  
----+-------
  1 | hello
  2 | world
  4 | foo
  5 | bar
```

- After:

```
 id | data  
----+-------
  1 | hello
  2 | world
  3 | foo
  4 | bar
```

I tried what was suggested in [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894162/compact-or-renumber-ids-for-all-tables-and-reset-sequences-to-maxid), but it didn't work:

```
# alter sequence t_id_seq restart;
ALTER SEQUENCE
# update t set id=default;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint t_pkey
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Comment: Restarting the sequence does not affect existing rows. If you want to close the gaps, you need to renumber the rows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, gaps in a sequence are to be expected. Ask yourself if you really need to remove them. Your life gets simpler if you just live with it. To get gap-less numbers, the (often better) alternative is to use a `VIEW` with `row_number()`. Example in this related answer:

- [Gap-less sequence where multiple transactions with multiple tables are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578288/939860)

Here are some recipes to remove gaps.

### 1. New, pristine table

Avoids complications with unique violations and table bloat and is *fast*. Only for ***simple cases*** where you are not bound by FK references, views on the table or other depending objects, or by concurrent access. Do it in *one* transaction to avoid accidents:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK tbl; -- optionally: IN SHARE MODE to allow concurrent reads

CREATE TABLE tbl_new (LIKE tbl INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO tbl_new -- no target list in this case
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id), data  -- all columns in default order
FROM   tbl;

ALTER SEQUENCE tbl_id_seq OWNED BY tbl_new.id;  -- make new table own sequence

DROP TABLE tbl;
ALTER TABLE tbl_new RENAME TO tbl;

SELECT setval('tbl_id_seq', max(id)) FROM tbl;  -- reset sequence

COMMIT;
```

[`CREATE TABLE tbl_new (LIKE tbl INCLUDING ALL)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) copies the structure incl. constraints and defaults from the original table. Then make the new table column own the sequence:

- [Activerecord-import & serial column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746762/939860)

And reset it to the new maximum:

- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860)

This carries the advantage that the new table is bloat-free and clustered on `id`.

### 2. `UPDATE` in place

This produces a lot of dead rows and requires (auto-) `VACUUM` later.

If the [`serial` column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69644/3684) is also the **`PRIMARY KEY`** (like in your case) or has a `UNIQUE` constraint, you must avoid **unique violations** in the process. The (cheaper) default for PK / UNIQUE constraints is to be `NOT DEFERRABLE`, which forces a check after every single single row. All details under this related question on SO:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860)

You could define your constraint as `DEFERRABLE` (which makes it more expensive).
**Or** you can drop the constraint and add it back when you are done:

```
BEGIN;

LOCK tbl;

ALTER TABLE tbl DROP CONSTRAINT tbl_pkey;  -- remove PK

UPDATE tbl t  -- intermediate unique violations are ignored now
SET    id = t1.new_id
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id FROM tbl) t1
WHERE  t.id = t1.id;

SELECT setval('tbl_id_seq', max(id)) FROM tbl;  -- reset sequence

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id); -- add PK back

COMMIT;
```

***Neither*** is possible while you have [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraints referencing the column(s) because ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)):

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique
> or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

You would need to (lock all involved tables and) drop / recreate FK constraints and update all FK values manually (see option *3.*). Or you have to move values out of the way with a second `UPDATE` to avoid conflicts. For instance, assuming you have no negative numbers:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK tbl;

UPDATE tbl SET id = id * -1;  -- avoid conflicts

UPDATE tbl t
SET    id = t1.new_id
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS new_id FROM tbl) t1
WHERE  t.id = t1.id;

SELECT setval('tbl_id_seq', max(id)) FROM tbl;  -- reset sequence

COMMIT;
```

Drawbacks as mentioned above.

### 3. Temp table, `TRUNCATE`, `INSERT`

One more option if you have plenty of RAM. This combines some of the advantages of the first two ways. Almost as fast as option *1.* and you get a pristine, new table without bloat but keep all constraints and dependencies in place like in option *2.*
**However**, [per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html)

> `TRUNCATE` **cannot be used on a table that has foreign-key references**
> from other tables, unless all such tables are also truncated in the
> same command. Checking validity in such cases would require table
> scans, and the whole point is not to do one.

Bold emphasis mine.

You could drop FK constraints temporarily and use data-modifying CTEs to update all FK columns:

```
SET temp_buffers = 500MB;   -- example value, see 1st link below

BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id, *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;  -- order here to use index (if one exists)

-- drop FK constraints in other tables referencing this one
-- which takes out an exclusive lock on those tables

TRUNCATE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT new_id, data  -- list all columns in order
FROM tbl_tmp;        -- rely on established order in tbl_tmp
-- ORDER BY id;      -- only to be absolutely sure (not necessary)

--  example for table "fk_tbl" with FK column "fk_id"
UPDATE fk_tbl f
SET    fk_id = t.new_id  -- set to new ID
FROM   tbl_tmp t
WHERE  f.fk_id = t.id;   -- match on old ID

-- add FK constraints in other tables back

COMMIT;
```

Related, with more details:

- [How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826879/939860)
- [How to “merge” two tables efficiently in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566086/939860)

Comment: If all `FOREIGN KEYS` are set to `CASCADE` couldn't you simply loop over the old primary keys and update their values in-place (from the old value to the new one)? Essentially this is option 3 without `TRUNCATE tbl`, replacing `INSERT` with an `UPDATE`, and without needing to update foreign keys manually.

Comment: @Gili: You *could*, but that kind of loop is extremely expensive. Since you cannot update the whole table at once due to unique key violations in the index, you need a separate `UPDATE` command for every row. See explanation in ② or try and see for yourself.

Comment: I don't think that performance is an issue in my case. The way I see it, there are two kinds of algorithms: ones that "stop the world" and ones that runs quietly in the background without having to take down the server. Assuming that compaction only occurs once in a blue moon (e.g. when approaching the upper limit of a data type), there isn't really an upper-limit on the amount of time it should take. So long as we are compacting records faster than new ones are being added, we should be fine.