# Generate incrementing IDs without sequences

Tags: postgresql, database-design, transaction, locking, sequence

Suppose there's a multi-tenant application where users can create some kind of documents with basic structure like

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT);
CREATE TABLE documents (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, document_id INT NOT NULL
, user_id INT NOT NULL
, text TEXT);
```

For each user `document_id` starts with 1 and increases preferably with gaps being a rare occurrence. The obvious solution is to create a sequence for each user get the `document_id` from there. But [according to this](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Maximum-number-of-sequences-that-can-be-created-td5702746.html#a5708255) databases don't behave well when there are lots of relations there. Another solution is to store `next_document_id` in `users` table and update it as necessary, but that means the lock on this row will be highly contested slowing simultaneous transactions from the same user. Any other ideas?

Comment: Tenants are companies and the application has something to do with accounting.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to *one* `serial` column per document and create a gap-less sequence per `user_id` dynamically in a `VIEW` - if you really need it.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, email text
);
CREATE TABLE document (
  document_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, user_id int NOT NULL
, document text);

CREATE VIEW document_with_rn_per_user AS
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                             ORDER BY document_id) AS doc_per_usr_id
FROM   document;
```

Never use basic type names like `text` as identifier. It's allowed, but it makes queries and error messages confusing. Generally, use descriptive names.

Related:

- [Compacting a sequence in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111823/compacting-a-sequence-in-postgresql/111824#111824)