# How to safely replace the old table with its cleaned copy?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, sequence, dependencies

I have created a `table_cleaned` like `table` and inserted unique values from `table` into `table_cleaned`. Now I want to replace `table` with `table_cleaned` with

```
DROP TABLE table;
ALTER TABLE table_cleaned rename to table;
```

but the first statement gives `cannot drop table cals_status because other objects depend on it`.

I definitely don't want to use `cascade` as it would delete all the dependent rows.

How can I safely replace the old table with its cleaned copy?

Following Erwin Brandstetter's advice, this is the missing detail of the error message:

> ```
> DETAIL:  default value for column id of table cals_status_deduplicated depends on sequence cals_status_id_seq
> ```

Answer (score 11):

By default, the error message tells you more. Like:

> ```
> ERROR: cannot drop table tbl because other objects depend on it
> SQL state: 2BP01
> Detail: view v_tbl depends on table tbl
> Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
> ```

#### General solution

Include the object mentioned in the `Detail` line in your script.

Also, to do it ***safely***, wrap all of it in a transaction, and write-lock the old table before working on the new to avoid losing work done during the transition:

```
BEGIN;

LOCK TABLE tbl IN SHARE MODE;

-- prepare tbl_cleaned

DROP VIEW v_tbl;  -- or any other depending object
-- more?

DROP TABLE tbl;
ALTER TABLE tbl_cleaned rename to tbl;

CREATE VIEW v_tbl AS SELECT  ... -- actual definition, see below
-- more?

COMMIT;
```

There may be more depending objects. Same procedure.

In the example, to get the view definition:

```
SELECT 'CREATE VIEW v_foo1 AS '
    || pg_get_viewdef('v_foo1'::regclass) AS view_definition;
```

See:

- [How to list the columns of a view in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58020843/939860)

And you may want to rename constraints and indices to fit the renamed table - or hold back on those and create with correct names *after* renaming the new table. (Again, be sure to get the definition before dropping the old table!)

Related:

- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/best-way-to-populate-a-new-column-in-a-large-table/52531#52531)
- [How do I replace a table in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32406198/939860)

If there are many depending objects and the table is not too big, a good **alternative** might be to prepare the new table (possibly as **temporary** table for better performance), then **`TRUNCATE`** the original and `INSERT` from the prepared new table. This way, depending objects like views, FK constraints, rules, function using the table type etc. can just stay in place. See:

- [Add new column without table lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412790/939860)

Or you might be able to update the old table in place? This related answer shows code for all three variants:

- [Compacting a sequence in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111823/compacting-a-sequence-in-postgresql/111824#111824)

#### Specific solution

Your particular error message:

```
DETAIL:  default value for column id of table cals_status_deduplicated depends on sequence cals_status_id_seq
```

... indicates that you are (ab-)using a sequence to generate default values for multiple tables. Or at least it's *owned* by the wrong column. The solution depends on how you want to deal with the situation.

Or you created the new table copying the complete structure *including* default values depending on the same sequence.

Typically, you want a dedicated sequence. So you should probably make the *new* column own the `SEQUENCE`:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE cals_status_id_seq OWNED BY tbl_cleaned.id;  -- column in new table *before* switching
```

`DROP TABLE` only cascades to the sequence if it's *owned* by one of the columns in the table to be dropped.

Related:

- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860)

You may be interested in `IDENTITY` columns which avoid this kind of complication with `serial` columns. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)