# Can one dictate the order of generated values when adding a new BIGSERIAL column to a table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-performance, identity, sequence

I need to add a new `BIGSERIAL` column to a huge table (~3 billion records). [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20801/224076) is similar to what I need to do and the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20802/224076) has helped me somewhat. But I'm still wondering about something. In my case, the table already has a `BIGSERIAL` column which is the primary key, but many rows have been deleted so now there are *gaps*. (The table has subsequently been fully vacuumed.) I need to regenerate the values so that they are sequential again. Here are 5 example rows of what I want to achieve where the `new_value > 1000`:

```
+---------+---------+
|old_value|new_value|
+---------+---------+
|1026     |1001     |
|1027     |1002     |
|1030     |1003     |
|1032     |1004     |
|1039     |1005     |
+---------+---------+
```

I have successfully implemented the alternative approach as mentioned in the referenced answer above (`CREATE TABLE ...`  and then `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM ...` ), but I would also like to attempt, and benchmark against, the initial suggestion. The problem, however, is that I don't know whether the `new_value` will be generated **in the same order** as the `old_value` as this is a requirement.

How can I ensure the order of the `new_value` column follows/tracks the order of the `old_value` column when the `new_value` column is added using a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE existing_table ADD COLUMN new_value BIGSERIAL;
```

### A different approach

I also attempted the following (that works quite well on a small table), but it's much slower than the alternative suggestion of the referenced answer on very large tables:

```
ALTER TABLE existing_table ADD COLUMN new_value BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE existing_table AS existing
SET new_value = generated.new_id
FROM (
      SELECT original.old_value
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY original.old_value) AS new_id
      FROM existing_table AS original
     ) generated
WHERE existing.old_value = generated.old_value;
```

Comment: What is your reason for this undertaking? It seems pointless to me.

Comment: As a side note (won't make a difference for your underlying "problem"): the use of the "serial" types [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favor of the standard compliant `identity` columns. But I do agree with Laurenz: this seems rather futile. Gaps are not a problem. The **only** job of a generated primary key is to be unique. It is completely irrelevant if there are gaps or what the actual value is.

Comment: More background: The table is the `domainevententry` table used in Axon and it has grown too large. We found that many events/records that are stored are not required (if we make some changes to our code). We are therefore busy with a clean-up project. Axon makes use of tracking tokens which can handle gaps, but it adds additional/unnecessary load on the DB to keep track of the gaps, so it's best if the values follow nice and sequential on each other.

Comment: How do you plan to update all tables _referencing_ the primary key of this table? Those values need to be changed in all other places as well.

Comment: Other tables don't reference the primary key column

Comment: so it's not needed as a primary key column, it's more of a sort-order column.

Comment: Yes @Jasen. Preserving the order is important for the Axon framework. There is also another unique index over two separate columns: `(aggregateidentifier, sequencenumber)`, but this index is only created after the clean-up/rebuild of the table is done.

Comment: Hmm, if that value is used for sorting, then why do the gaps matter? They won't change the sort order.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: We make use of Axon's `GapAwareTrackingToken`. When there are gaps then Axon could fire queries containing `WHERE globalindex IN ( ... list of gaps ... )`. When there are no gaps then the query doesn't use `WHERE globalindex IN`. This might not be a major issue for the live system, because it only cares about new rows that are inserted, but there is also the notion of a replay that's used in other circumstances which starts at the first row and runs through the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the advise in the comments: do you really need to remove gaps? Typically, you don't. And gaps will be creeping back in. See:

- [Is IDENTITY continuous in new versions of PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289986/is-identity-continuous-in-new-versions-of-postgresql/290022#290022)
- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918964/939860)

Next, consider the updates to my old answer you have been working off:

- [Most efficient way to add a serial column to a huge table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20801/most-efficient-way-to-add-a-serial-column-to-a-huge-table/20802#20802)

Among other things, how to possibly avoid writing WAL for the table data in the new table - that will be the most significant bit to further improve performance.

> How can I ensure the order of the `new_value` column follows/tracks the
> order of the `old_value` column when the `new_value` column is added using
> a statement like this:
>
> `ALTER TABLE existing_table ADD COLUMN new_value BIGSERIAL;`

You cannot. Use one of the other routes.

> I also attempted the following (that works quite well on a small table), but it's much slower than the alternative suggestion of the referenced answer on very large tables:

The `UPDATE` route is inherently more expensive than writing a pristine new table from scratch (adding indexes constraints afterwards).

Comment: Thanks @Erwin. You are correct, gaps do occur sometimes, but they are usually small and Axon is better at handling small gaps. The clean-up however will get rid of ~90% of the rows which will leave many, large gaps.